# Reuse @Composable container for a list of items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
data class object1()

data class object2()
```

In my @Composable screen I have 2 tabs, every single display a list with items.

```
when (tabToDisplay) {
    TabCategory.1-> Section1(list = listOf<object1>())
    TabCategory.2-> Section2(list = listOf<object2>())
}
```

`@Section1` and `@Section2` is the same composable with

```
 Column(){
    list.forEach {
       UiItem1()
   //or
       UiItem2()
    }
}
```

The only difference inside is the type of item I'm creating.

Question:
How I can simplify my code to have only 1 `@Composable` section for my list object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a generic parameter and a content builder to your `Section`:

```
@Composable
fun<T> Section(list: List<T>, itemContent: @Composable (T) -> Unit) {
    Column(){
        list.forEach {
            itemContent(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can it like this:

```
when (tabToDisplay) {
    TabCategory.1 -> {
        Section(list = listOf<Object1>()) {
            UiItem1(it)
        }
    }
    TabCategory.2 -> {
        Section(list = listOf<Object2>()) {
            UiItem2(it)
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. according to [kotlin style guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#type_names), classes should be named in PascalCase. When you get used to this, it will increase your development speed because your eye will more easily identify the variable/class in your code. It is also required in most development commands, so it is better to get used to it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parentClass for both models, lets say `ParentObjClazz`

Keep a single composable `@Section` and that takes `TabCategory` and list of `ParentObjClazz`

```
@Composable
fun Section(tabCategory: TabCategory, list: List<ParentObjClazz>) {
  //...
}
```

Cast the objects and populate the view according to `tabCategory` or child class `type` checking